# 'Unknown server tag' as I'm trying to use a custom control

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, class

I'm a complete autodidact and never had added new classes to a Visual Studio project before. I stepped now on [this](http://hermanussen.eu/sitecore/wordpress/2011/04/prevent-nullrefs-when-databinding-with-placeholders/) post which seems pretty cool and therefore wanted to implement the described class and control.

I added a new class to my asp.net project DesignProject and pasted the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace DesignProject
{
    public class DataPlaceHolder : PlaceHolder
    {
        protected override void DataBindChildren()
        {
            if (Visible)
            {
                base.DataBindChildren();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I use the control DataPlaceHolder in the markup? I've been trying with DesignProject:DataPlaceHolder.... but Unknown server tag 'DesignProject:DataPlaceHolder'.

Martin

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="myControl" Namespace="DesignProject" Assembly="MyApp" %>
```

Comment: You were right, although I had to do several steps first, as I had just added the class to the project were I wanted to use it. This doesn't seem to work that work as I learned now. One has to build the custom control as a proper project first. Afterwards add its reference to the project, were the custom control is going to be used and then your line comes in!